# Angular 5 - Unable to 2 way bind data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I feel like this might be a basic question but after a week of doing research I cant figure out what I am messing up. Ill admit im not too comfortable with Angular (2++).

I am trying to create a simple CRUD system. I created a button on each row of my data table and added click events for each. This event will call a function on my service that would redirect me to the my form and populate my var CurrentIncident with its data. So far so good everything is connected great and I see the data from my console as expected:

Example data returned:

```
{ description: "This is a test", data1: "Another test", data2: "Another test"}
```

Next step was to setup a 2 way bind on my form using NgModel. So I added this in my inputs.

```
<input placeholder="Description" value="" [(ngModel)]="CurrentIncident.Description">
```

But it returns with the error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined

Would anyone know where im messing up?

Button event:

```
<button mat-mini-fab color="accent" (click)="CrudService.Edit_Incident(this.params.data)">
    <mat-icon aria-label="Edit">description</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Incident_Model } from '../incident_model';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class CrudService {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    public CurrentIncident: Incident_Model[];

    public Edit_Incident(data) {
        this.CurrentIncident = data;
        this.router.navigate(['form'])
        console.log( this.CurrentIncident )
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="40">
    <input matInput placeholder="Description" value="">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `CrudService` class, `CurrentIncident` is expected to be an array, though it is not given any value in the constructor.

That's why in your template

```
[(ngModel)]="CurrentIncident.Description"
```

`CurrentIncident` is initially `undefined`.

On top of that, given that `CurrentIncident` is an array, it will not have a `Description` property. Given your sample data you might use something like

```
[(ngModel)]="CurrentIncident[0].description"
```

But only once your `CurrentIncident` has been initialized.

To prevent errors until is `CurrentIncident` initialized, you could use [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#most-common-usage)

```
<input placeholder="Description" value="" [(ngModel)]="CurrentIncident[0].description" *ngIf="CurrentIncident">
```

Comment: Still seems to return an error, this time im getting this error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: This was only an example. `CurrentIncident[0].description` means that `CurrentIncident` is an array whose first element is an object that has a `description` property.

Comment: Ok I understand that but im not understanding the solution. Would you have an example of the solution?

Comment: Is `CurrentIncident` really supposed to be an array (as you declared in TypeScript) or an object (which would make more sense looking at your code)?

Comment: Its returning a single object. Now that you mentioned it, I removed the array on the CurrentIncident   `public CurrentIncident: Incident_Model;` but still seem to get the same errors tough.